# $_SESSION login x logout button script don't run, one more, cause it was marked as duplicate

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've been doing a webpage with register/login php script. Everything works fine except $_SESSION variable, which should change login button to logout button. Idk, where I could be wrong. Can anyone help me please?

**my header.php**
    There is also < ?php session_start(); ?> on the beggining of both files, but i can't show that inside this editor.

```
<body>
<header>
<nav>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Loginsystem</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="nav-login">
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
                echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
            </form>';
            } else {
                echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/email">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
            <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

**Login script**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);

//Error handlers
//Checks if inputs aren't empty
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' OR user_email = 
'$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing pwd
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                //Loging user
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row[$user_id];
                $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row[$user_name];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row[$user_email];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row[$user_uid];
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
        } 
    }
}
} else {
header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
exit();
```

Comment: Not related to your problem: `<form action="includes/logout.inc.php">` `.inc.php` files are usually only included in other files and not called directly.

Comment: So, what i should change in it?

Comment: Nothing really, as I said it's not related to your problem. You can keep it as it is if it's working. Just a notice that I personally wouldn't link/call `.inc.php` files.

Comment: Ahh ok then.. I'm using it, because i want to distinguish templates from files with php functional scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);

//Error handlers
//Checks if inputs aren't empty
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$uid' OR user_email = 
'$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing pwd
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
            /* Login user, check if session has started, if not start it */

                if(session_id()=='')
                {
                    session_start();
                }

                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row[$user_id];
                $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row[$user_name];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row[$user_email];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row[$user_uid];
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
        } 
    }
}
} else {
header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
exit();
```

Comment: @DavidPleva Yes, check the answer. Thanks